# Fuzzy matching assertions fails - Edge case

Tags: karate

Below is the scenario which can be executed to replicate the issue-

```
Scenario: get all posts
    * url 'https://reqres.in/'
    Given path '/api/users/2'
    When method delete
    Then status 204
    And match response.id == '#null'
    And match response.time == '#present'
```

For this request, there are only response headers with no response body. But the above assertion to validate null and presence of a field are passing.

As per the karate documentation, both of these assertions expect JSON key to be present. Based on that, i was expecting the assertions to fail even though there is no response body. Is this a bug in karate?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the response is not JSON, so those `#present` kinds of assertions won't work. The recommendation is to always use JSON objects to match. For example:

```
* match response == { id: '#null', time: '#present' }
```

This avoids the problem you experienced. We opened an issue anyway, which provides more explanation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2406